# Sometimes I get Database Logon Failed and sometimes I don't

Tags: crystal-reports

Using Crystal Reports VS2010. This problem is occurring in production--hosting provided by arvixe. Sometimes when I generate the report I get the Database Logon Failed asp.net error. Sometimes it works just fine. What can I do to fix this so it works 100% of the time? I'm not actually connecting to a database here. Just using ASP.NET objects.

Comment: You say you are not using a DB. Is your report using saved data? Are you using the ReportDocument at all? If so you can trap your errors by using reportDocument.VerifyDatabase(); before they bubble up.

Comment: Nothing has been saved yet, I'm using .NET objects I'm populating via a jQuery form. I'm using validation on the form to make sure everything has been filled in, but I'm still getting an error somewhere. I'll try using VerifyDatabase() to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Can you post the connection string/relevant code? Also suggest checking the TTL response times from the content provider - log them on continual basis until problem resolved. Could be network problem, ISP, etc.

Comment: Isolating the source of the problem can lead to the solution. Step through the code to determine which line in the code is raising the error. Is it before the report calls the .NET objects or after?

Answer (score 0):

For intermittent errors that are not readily reproducible, comprehensive logging (at multiple places in the code) is a standard solution that can help you isolate the cause.